# Why since my switch to discord js 13, the messageCreate Event bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I explain my problem: I use a js file external to my commands for my Events and I have the impression that there are some things that do not work correctly in my messageCreate.js which however worked before with Discord .JS in version 12.
For example, when I want to return as soon as the bot sends a message it doesn't work via the messageCreate.js, I have to put it in all of my commands etc.

In my commands I noticed that the arguments do not work whereas before I had no problems. I was able to verify this by putting a

```
if(args == undefined) return console.log("test")
```

and the message "test" was displayed in the console as soon as I tried.

I put my code below, hoping you can help me. :)

the part of my index.js that deals with events:

```
fs.readdir("./Events/", (err, files) => {
    Debug.logs(`[${chalk.cyan(moment(Date.now()).format('h:mm:ss'))}] ${chalk.cyan('Chargement des évènements ...')}`)

    if (err) return Debug.logs(err)

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
        if (file.endsWith(".js")) {
            const event = require(`./Events/${file}`)
            let eventName = file.split(".")[0]
            try {
                bot.on(eventName, event.bind(null, bot))
                delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./events/${file}`)]
                Debug.logs(`[${chalk.cyan(moment(Date.now()).format('h:mm:ss'))}] ${chalk.green('Event Chargé :')} ${chalk.cyan(file)}`)
            } catch (error) {
                Debug.logs(error)
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    })
})
```

my messageCreate.js :

```
const env = process.env
const chalk = require('chalk')
const moment = require('moment')
const Debug = require('../utils/Debug')
const config = require("../config.json")

module.exports = async (bot, message) => {
    
    if(message.channel.type === "DM"){
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        message.reply("Les commandes en **messages privés** sont actuellement **désactivées** !")
        Debug.logs(`[${chalk.cyan(moment(Date.now()).format('h:mm:ss'))}] [${chalk.yellow(message.author.tag)}] a envoyé ${chalk.green(message.content)} en DM`)
    }else{
    if (!message.author.bot) {
        if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) {
            const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
            const cmd = bot.commands.get(command)
        
            if (cmd) {
                await cmd.run(bot, message, args)
                Debug.logs(`[${chalk.cyan(moment(Date.now()).format('h:mm:ss'))}] [${chalk.yellow(message.author.tag)}] a utilisé ${chalk.green(command)} ${chalk.cyan(args.join(" "))}`)
            } else {
                return
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
}
}
```

and one exemple of command who not work with messageCreate.js :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, config, args) => {

    message.delete();

        if(args == undefined) return console.log("wtf that not work ?")
}

module.exports.help = {
    name:"test",
    desc:"test commands !",
    usage:"test",
    group:"autre",
    examples:"$test"
}

module.exports.settings = {
    permissions:"false",
    disabled:"false",
    owner:"false"
}
```

as soon as I run the command with argument or without any argument, in both cases the console receives the message "wtf that not work?"

I hope you can help me! thanks in advance :)

Sorry if my english is bad but i'm french, not english !

Answer (score 0):

In `messageCreate.js`, you call your command with the following:

```js
// 3 arguments
await cmd.run(bot, message, args);
```

However, your command's run function is defined with 4 parameters:

```js
async (bot, message, config, args) => {
  // config = 'args', and args = undefined
}
```

To fix the issue, either:

- Pass in a value for `config`, such as `null`:

  ```js
  await cmd.run(bot, message, null, args);
  ```
- Make your function only have 3 parameters:

  ```js
  async (bot, message, args) => {
    // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Indeed, the problem concerning the arguments came from there, thank you! :)

Do you know on the other hand why the return is not done when it comes to the bot that sends a message?
I have to put the `if(message.author.bot) return`
to all the places where I need it whereas before with discord.js 12 I just had to put it in the messageCreate.js and it was enough.

Comment: Unless you have a command that responds to bot messages, you really only need to have one `if(message.author.bot) return` call at the start of your logic in the `messageCreate`. This code is just not refactored enough.

Comment: For example, in this code there: https://pastebin.com/zUhPdA0n (sorry i have to put it on pastebin otherwise my message is too long)
In this example, the bot responds to its message with "entre un nombre valide !" and I have to add the `if(message.author.bot) return`
for it to work whereas before with discord js 12 it was enough that I put it in the messageCreate.js for it to work.
Is this normal?

Comment: In both v12 and v13, you should have needed to have `if(message.author.bot) return` in your code. Well, the code would work without it, but using that prevents accidental bot loops, or responding to other bots.

Comment: Ah it seemed to me however that putting it only in the messageCreate.js was enough before but maybe I am wrong.
so i will put it on as soon as i need it.

Thank you for your help and wish you a good end of the day! :)